# How to get json text by request with header details?

Tags: python, json, request, header

I would like to go to page https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one and write json text from there.
End at first I must login in https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one_login and use
details in header.

But if If I run code I see:

**raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None 

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Do you know how to rewrite it?
(Header data are correct)

Thank you

```
import json
import requests

headers = {
    'username': 'Loskarlos',
    'password':  'JednohoDneOvladnuKSI'
}


response = requests.post('https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one_login', headers=headers)
        
response_get = requests.get('https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one ')
    
response_get = json.loads(response_get.json())
    
print(response_get)
```

Comment: Please dont post username and passwords in questions in the future. Thanks hope you found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the token from `https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one_login` in order to test the API use postman. Your initial response is not a header element. It is a form, use below code to get the token.

```
import requests

url = "https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one_login"

payload={'username': '<User NAME>',
'password': '<Password>'}

headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

After this I have no idea to pass the token header as per below code. Use header parameters when consuming the part_one endpoint. For header use Bearer  format to build the Authorization header parameter.

```
import requests

url = "https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <TOKEN>'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

As a practice use [postman](https://www.postman.com/) like tool to navigate an API. cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
url = "https://losoviny.iamroot.eu/part_one_login"

payload={'username': 'Loskarlos',
'password': 'JednohoDneOvladnuKSI'}

headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```